# Переключение страниц с помощью include

Tags: php

Как можно сделать чтобы страгицы переключались с помощью include для меню из нескольких фалов `index.php`?

Comment: Уточните, что вам надо, может, приведите пример того, что у вас есть и что бы вы хотели получить в итоге

Comment: Я создал меню <ul>
<li>меню
</li>
<li>программы
</li>
</ul>

Чтобы эти страницы переключались черещ php

Comment: Что значит "переключались через PHP"? Создайте на каждом li ссылку, в атрибуте href которой укажите ссылку на нужную страницу.